# iOS WebKit No Audio

Tags: ios, swift, audio, webrtc

I am using WebRTC to get audio and video, but I am having an issue where the audio is silent. It works on Chrome and Android, and is only failing in iOS. My code is as follows:

```
    <wkWebView 
contentMode="scaleToFill" 
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iea-Pu-Gia">                    
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="818"/>                    
<color 
key="backgroundColor" 
red="0.36078431370000003" 
green="0.38823529410000002" 
blue="0.4039215686" 
alpha="1" 
'colorSpace="custom" 
customColorSpace="sRGB"/>                    
<wkWebViewConfiguration 
key="configuration" 
allowsInlineMediaPlayback="YES">                      
<audiovisualMediaTypes 
key="mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback" 
audio="NO" video="NO"/>                      
<wkPreferences key="preferences"/>                    
</wkWebViewConfiguration>                  
</wkWebView>
```

Any suggestions I what to configure to get the audio automatically working without user gesture?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is enforced by default, in the interests of stopping unwanted playback and preserving battery life.

You can set an override to this behaviour in code, for example:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    webConfiguration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
}
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1851524-mediatypesrequiringuseractionfor